# How do i stop echo in loop and re-run case statement?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Pretty new to bash scripting , I was learning how to use multiple cases and inputs in case statement.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Choose from 1,2" 
read -p "Enter here : " input1
echo "Choose from a,b" 
read -p "Enter here : " input2

while true; do
case $input1+$input2 in
  1+a )
    echo "You have chosen 1 and a"
     break;;
  1+b )
    echo "You have chosen 1 and b"
    break;;
  2+a )
   echo "You have chosen 2 and a"
    break;;
  2+b )
   echo "You have chosen 2 and b"
    break;;
  *+* )
    echo "Invalid input";;
esac
done
```

PS \ I know i can use single wildcard asterisk in to cover remaining possibilities , i just used it twice for times when i need wildcard only for single case and not both of them together.

Currently

- Everything else works fine , but if i try to invoke invalid output by entering random numbers , it is infinitely spamming - Invalid output .

Expectation

- if user inputs anything which is not covered by case statement , echo "invalid output" only once and rerun the case statement ( ie echo those 2 questions again )

Can someone please suggest how do i fix it

Comment: Put the `read` inside the loop.

Comment: @Beta thanks its working well now , although there's small thing i wanted to fix. Lets say i enter the first question correctly and only input the second one wrong , it reruns both cases. How do i make it run only those cases for which input was wrong

Comment: Put another loop around each read and validate each one independently...

Comment: @DavidSainty thanks for the idea of directly validating the read itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the suggested comments , i came up with this

```
while true; do
echo "Choose from 1,2" 
read -p "Enter here : " input1
case $input1 in
  1|2 )
    break;;
   * )
     echo "Enter Valid Input"
esac
done

while true; do
echo "Choose from a,b" 
read -p "Enter here : " input2
case $input2 in
  a|b )
    break;;
    * )
    echo "Enter Valid Input"
esac
done

case $input1+$input2 in
  1+a )
    echo "You have chosen 1 and a";;
  1+b )
    echo "You have chosen 1 and b";;
  2+a )
   echo "You have chosen 2 and a";;
  2+b )
   echo "You have chosen 2 and b";;
esac
```

Comment: Perhaps write a function `readoption()` that takes the valid input as arguments. And know: `input1=$(readoption 1 2); input2=$(readoption a b);`